# How do I view the Django Server on my phone?

Tags: django

How can I view my app from the Django developer server on my phone?

I am trying to access the web app from my Nexus phone.

Comment: Can I ask why you even need to? Most modern browsers include a developer console that offers the ability to see what the website will look like on a mobile resolution

Comment: @Sayse Final tests for usability using touch/scrolling on phone is always useful and can't be reproduced on a 24" non-touchscreen display.

Answer (score 6):

You need to start the server so that it listens on all the network interfaces on your computer. You can do so as follows:

```
 ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then if your computer's IP is 192.168.1.2 for example just type 192.168.1.2:8000 into your phone browser but make sure it's connected to wifi